How to put a try and except TypeError inside a while statement
I need to see if the user input is a float or not. However, I need the question to keep asking the user to re input until it is a float.
    try:
        float(a)
    except TypeError:
        while float(a) != a:
         a = input(f"'{a}' is not a valid input. Please enter a number: ")

This does not work because I get an error the moment I do float(a) if a is not a float. What should I do to put a try and error inside of a while statement.

"I get an error the moment I do float(a) if a is not a float" - Wait, that doesn't make sense. float() is meant to turn non-floats into floats, e.g. float('0.9') → 0.9. What error are you getting? Is it a NameError? That would have a totally different cause. I closed the question as a duplicate, which at least shows you the pattern you should be following, but now IDK if it directly answers your question since you haven't provided enough details.

Also, float(a) != a doesn't make sense if a is a string since a string and a float will never compare equal (unlike in JavaScript, if that's where you're coming from).

You want ValueError, not TypeError.
The while float(a) part is not inside of the try block, it's in the except, so any errors it raises don't get caught.
Because you want to repeatedly do the try/except, it must come inside the while loop. The easiest way to do this, imo, is to use a while True: and then break when there isn't an error using an else on the try
a = input('Enter a number: ')
while True:
  try:
    float(a)
  except ValueError:
    # float(a) raised a ValueError, so prompt again.
    a = input(f"'{a}' is not a valid input. Please enter a number: ")
  else:
    break # exit the loop when there wasn't an error

